# Pandas converts the date column to an integer and displaying the whole column as integer values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I tried to pull an excel where I have a column as "ORDER LINE CREATE DATE" which consists of date values in **MM/DD/YYYY** format.

Now when I use the **pd.read_excel('File path')**
it treats the date column as an integer value and displays an integer instead of date time
for ex. the date **7/15/2022** when imported is automatically converted to the value **44757** and similarly the date **7/14/2022** when imported gets automatically converted to the value **44756**

What is causing this problem and how can I import the date in the same format as that in the excel,
I tried using **dtype={'ORDER LINE CREATE DATE':"string"}** and even **dtype={'ORDER LINE CREATE DATE':"datetime64"}** during the excel import but it still fails.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel('File path')
df['ORDER LINE CREATE DATE'] = df['ORDER LINE CREATE DATE'].apply(
   lambda x: datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + int(x) - 2))
```

Comment: updated the solution

Comment: This works great in cases where the excel file wasn't formatting as date properly and shows as an int (even in excel).    I have files that sometimes are and sometimes aren't formatted date so I use,   
if df['ORDER LINE CREATE DATE'].dtype==int64:
     df['ORDER LINE CREATE DATE'] = df['ORDER LINE CREATE DATE'].apply(
   lambda x: datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + int(x) - 2))