# Pandas Converts My date string value in date column to an integer

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file which I am using `pd.read_excel()` to read, inside the excel file are couple of date columns (the date data type is a string and must follow this format: `dd/mm/yyyy`. The problem I have is that when the excel file gets converted to a dataframe using `pd.read_excel()`, the values gets converted into an integer.

Does anyone know how I can maintain the value in the excel file after it has been converted to a dataframe.

Screenshot below:
**The columns with the date format**
[image]

**What the values get converted to after converting the file to a dataframe**
[image]

"43800" is what the value of "Incorporation Date" got converted to.

**What I have tried:**

```
for column in columns_with_date_string:
    client_entity_df[column] = pd.to_datetime(
        client_entity_df[column].astype(int)
    )
    client_entity_df[column] = client_entity_df[column].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

This approach returned the values as "01/01/1970", instead of the dates specified

**TLDR:**

I basically want to maintain the value of my date columns (12/11/2022) in my excel file where the format is "dd/mm/yyy" when the excel file gets converted to a dataframe, pandas currently changes the values to an integer (which I assume is an epoch) when it converts the file to an integer.

Comment: It's not Pandas converting the date, it's Excel itself. That's how it stores dates internally.

Comment: I see, so I guess it was that internal representation that Pandas was picking up?

Comment: Yes. You can see it in Excel by changing the cell format from date to numeric. It's the number of days since [1899-12-30](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3963617/5987).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df_excel = pd.read_excel(file, dtype=object)
```

All columns became a object type and after that you can convert in another type if you need:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_excel['column_name'])
```

Comment: This just converts it to 01/12/1970 instead of the value in the column

Answer (score 0):

So I got a solution to it:

```
for column in columns_with_date_string:
    df[column] = df[column].apply(
        lambda x: datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + int(x) - 2)
    )
    df[column] = df[column].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73441865/pandas-converts-the-date-column-to-an-integer-and-displaying-the-whole-column-as) was helpful.

Comment: Use `1899, 12, 30` and remove the `- 2`.

Comment: Hey @MarkRansom, thanks for your comment. Quick question: Why do you think what you suggested is preferred instead of what I used? Honest question here as I'd like to learn

Comment: Mostly just because it's simpler, and more accurately reflects what's going on.